# Tab to Window or Vice Versa in Firefox AddOn

Tags: firefox-addon

In a Firefox AddOn, is there a way to get a window object from a tab object?  Or vice versa?  For instance, if I get a TabClose event, is there a way to get the associated window object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in TabClose the event argument holds a lot of useful stuff:

```
function tabclosee(e) {
  console.error('TabClose, e:', e);
}

gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener("TabAttrModified", tabclosee, false);
```

[image]

So in this image we see that `e.view` is the `DOMWindow` (xul window/chrome window).  The target is the tab element, in the close situation the HTMLWindow was destoryed so `e.target.linkedBrowser` will be null, but in `TabSelect` it won't be null and you can access the html window like `e.target.linkedBrowser.contentWindow`

If you want window from tab object you can do this too: `e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView`, this is the same as doing `e.view` above.

From window you can access all tabs like this:

```
if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser && aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
 var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
 for (var t=0; t<tabs.length; t++) {
  var tab = tabs[t];
  var tab_linkedBrowser = tab.linkedBrowser;
  var tab_htmlWin = tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow;
 }
}
```